# Adding an external image to a views output

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to alter the output of a view  with a tpl.php file. My goal is to insert an image immediately after another image in the view. This should only happen for 1 result. That is to say, if the value of my array image is apple, I want to also display another image of apples. So if I have a view that returns images of fruits:

- Grapes
- pears
- apple
- peaches
- bananas

I want to display these images:

- Grapes
- pears
- apple apple1
- peaches
- bananas

I'm open to ideas, so far I've been trying to solve the issue programatically by creating a custom .tpl file for the view, but if a cleaner solution exists I'd be willing to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that I believe the best/easiest way to do this is by adding another field to my content type, and inserting the associated image in that field. Even though I've created a field in that content type that is only required for one piece of content.

Comment: Why don't you use something like Taxonomy. Create one for Fruit with terms for each type and add an image field. Then for your content type you add a term reference to that and pull the image via the term reference into views. That way you are re-using content and can change the image once only if need be.

Comment: Thanks, this idea would also work, however in order to keep the structure of this site consistent, I think I will still stick with the additional field.